# When I'm running TestRunner class using junit Cucumber , i 'm getting 0 Scenarios 0 Steps 0m0.000s

Tags: java, junit, cucumber, bdd

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeAz7.png)[image]

Added Screenshots of Project Structure and pom file.
Please let me know if there is anything that i need to add in the project.

[image]

Comment: From what you posted there is no class/method that has `@Test` which indicates an actual test

Comment: Use junit4, junit 5 is not supported. Also upgrade cucumber version https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java

Comment: I have updated my pom file with cucumber v4.2.0 and junit with 4.12 and ran once again. Now, getting below error:                                                                          java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/datatable/dependency/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType
 at io.cucumber.datatable.DataTableType.<init>(DataTableType.java:78)
 at io.cucumber.datatable.DataTableTypeRegistry.<init>(DataTableTypeRegistry.java:27)
 at io.cucumber.stepexpression.TypeRegistry.<init>(TypeRegistry.java:

Comment: Added Error and stepdef file in the screenshot

Comment: Can u add the updated pom

Comment: <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
<version>4.2.0</version> <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
   <version>4.2.0</version><artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
   <version>4.2.0</version><artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.6</version>